# Laravel Collection Determine if Many to Many Relationship Exists

Tags: php, laravel, collections, model

Using Laravel 5.6, I have a many to many relationship between User and Assessment (a test), with a pivot table called "attempts". I'm trying to loop through all my Assessments and determine if a user has passed or not (due to failing or not taking an assessment(nonexistance of relationship)).

I'm trying to use the "contains" method, but probably not using it correctly.

In my User.php model file I have the following that isn't working correctly:

```
/*
* Relationship between User and Assessments
*/
public function assessments(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Assessment', 'attempts', 'user_id', 'assessment_id')->withPivot('is_passing', 'score');
}

/*
* Get all Assessments but determine if a user has passed them or not
*/
public function getPassOrFailAttribute() {
    $passed = $this->assessments->where('pivot.is_passing', 1);
    $assessments = Assessment::all();
    foreach($assessments as $assessment) {
        // *** This is the part that doesn't seem to be working correctly ***
        $assessment['passorfail'] = $assessment->contains('id', $passed->id);
    }
    return $assessments;
}
```

Ultimately I want to loop through all assessments in my blade view and style the output differently depending on if a user passed or failed, like such:

```
@foreach($user->passOrFail as $assessment)
    @if($assessment->passorfail)
        <div class="panel-block">
            {{ $assessment->name}}
        </div>
    @else
        <a href="{{ route('visitor.assessments.show', $assessment) }}" class="panel-block">
            {{ $assessment->name}}
        </a>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Your collection->where is looking at the wrong level I think.  is_passing will be nested one level deeper in pivot ... I think.

Comment: You are correct, that I needed to nest the is_passing one level deeper in the getPassOrFailAttribute. I've updated my original post with that, but I'm still stuck on the foreach loop and determining if the $assessments contain the $passed assessments or not.

Comment: The line in the foreach is using $assessment as an array and as an object.